# How to train an LSTM-network on the following data?

Tags: python, pytorch, dataset, lstm, pytorch-dataloader

I have some data in the following format:
[image]

As you can see, I have these values of 1,2 and 3 with different and random sequences in the Request column. According to this frequency, the slot which is then selected is given in the Selected Slot column in the format [1 0] (for a frequency of 2 and the selected slot being the first one), [1 0 0] (for a frequency of 3 and selected slot being the first one) and so on.

Here's what I tried:

In the dataset_class -

```
class csv_dataset_df(Dataset):
    # load the dataset
    def __init__(self, dataframe):
        # store the inputs and outputs
        self.df = dataframe
        
        self.categorical = ['Request','Slot EST','Slot LST','Slot EFT','Slot LFT','Slot Start Loc','Slot End Loc','Task Pickup Loc','Task Dropoff Loc','Task Duration']
        self.target = ['Makespan', 'Selected slot']
        
        self.X = np.array(self.df[self.categorical]) 
        self.y = np.array(self.df[self.target])

        self.list_ids = np.arange(0, self.X.shape[0])
    
 
    # number of rows in the dataset
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.list_ids)
    
    def __shape__(self):
        return self.df.shape
 
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
    # For the current index, see what the request is and get all the consecutive rows with the same request
    # Return the X and y values for the consecutive rows
    start = idx 
    current_request = self.X[start, 0]
    for i in range(start, self.X.shape[0]):
        if self.X[i, 0] != current_request:
            end = i
            break

    # Remove the obtained indexes from the getitem list so that they are not used again]
    self.list_ids = np.delete(self.list_ids, np.arange(start, end))

    X = self.X[start:end, :]
    y = self.y[start:end, :]

    self.pad_length = 7 

    # Pad the y values, which is a 2D array, if smaller than the length pad_length, with 0s on both dimensions 
    if X.shape[0] < self.pad_length:
        y = np.pad(y, ((0, self.pad_length - X.shape[0]), (0, 0)), 'constant', constant_values=0)

    return X,y
```

For the output, I checked the maximum frequency by which a request occurred (7 in this case) and thought about padding all the outputs accordingly to this length.

I have been very confused as to whether this is the right way to go about it, because I have also read things about the EndOfSentence tokens which someone suggested I could use but I am not sure. The variable length input I think is something that can be handled but I don't know if a variable length output is possible with an LSTM or not.

Is this method correct or is there any other way I could go on about it?

Comment: Input sequences of variable lengths are very common in NLP, for example, when you have sentences of different lengths you want to classifier using LSTM-based network. For starters, you can check [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/tensorflow-esque-bucket-by-sequence-length/41284/15) about basic methods to handle this.